# populate data in ng-repeat with dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list which I am populating through ng-repeat and in that list I have a nested list with a button on each  . Now upon clicking that ul i want to load list from server which can be dynamic. Currently it is overiding the field. Here is my code.

```
<ul class="qtree">
  <li ng-repeat="Childgroup in childGroups">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del-btn-tree" data-ng-click="deleteChildGroup(Childgroup.id)" ></span>
    <label for="test1">{{Childgroup.name}}</label>                         
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{Childgroup.id}}" data-ng-click="getEntities(Childgroup.id)" />
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="entity in entites">
         {{entity.name}}
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.getEntities = function(groupID) {

$scope.entites = [];
var entitiesGroup = ManageGroupsFactory.getEntitiesForGroup(groupID);
entitiesGroup.success(function(entitiesGroup) {
  if(entitiesGroup != "") {                 
    for(var i=0; i<entitiesGroup.length;i++) {
        $scope.entites.push(entitiesGroup[0]);
    }
  }
});

entitiesGroup.error(function(data,status){
     // TODO for errors
});
```

The first list populates fine through ng-repeat. Now what I want is upon clicking the checkbox it load's it's specific entities from server and populates in it and every checkbox will have different entites inside it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you are updating `$scope.entites` in a asynch operation you should use `$scope.$apply()` after updating the object.

Comment: Basically what I meant is there is a list each having a expandable button. now if a user expands list item 1 it should see entity related to first list item. and if user clicks 2nd item in list it should see list items related to second. Currently what is happening is on first it show correct but when i expand 2nd list item it also override the first list data with second one.

Comment: add a fiddle or plunker with your problem, that will make things clear.

Comment: @Mritunjay Please see the plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/4sDyA6e2HzE6eIOGYy04?p=preview

clicking on radio button will have to load entities related to that child and each child will have different entities.  I have put the comments also.

Answer (score 0):

One technique that has a good chance of working is to generate unique id's for each of the elements in the sub lists. You should be able to combine the parent list name + some value of the inner loop to generate a unique id, eg:

```
<li ng-repeat="entity in entites track by $id(Childgroup.id + entity.name)">
     {{entity.name}}
</li>
```

Let me know how that works for you.